# How to detect Restricted mode?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

How can I detect `Restricted`, `Synchronizing`, and `Synchronized` mode on a database? Are there other modes?

Yes, I know that is is visible in SSMS. I need a script to detect it.

Comment: As a general tip: SSMS uses only T-SQL to do its job. You can always use SQL Server Profiler to trace the queries it executes to find out where it gets its data. These "modes" are not true singular database states, but an amalgamation of different columns.

Comment: @JeroenMostertm, I would like to use SQL Server Profiler, but I do not have the required permission. I am looking for something like SELECT ? FROM ? that can be run as a mere mortal user.

Comment: The query itself is far too large to post, nor is it clear how Management Studio derives its display from the query data (it doesn't simply distill it into a description in the query), but I can tell you it uses `sys.databases.is_in_standby`, `sys.databases.state`, `sys.databases.user_access`, `sys.databases.is_read_only` and `sys.database_mirroring.mirroring_state`. These views are documented and should allow you to recreate what SSMS shows (possibly though some experimentation). `Restricted`, specifically, should be `user_access = 2`.